# Lenght of form-inline's input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to use "col" notation to make inline form input wider?

As for now input field is short or can be widen with `size` like this:

```
 <div class="row">

        <form action="index.php" method="GET" class="form-inline" role="form">


            <input class="form-control"  size=50  name="email" />
```

But how to stretch the input to fit columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you'd put your `form-control` inside a `form-group`, and then apply the `col-*` to the `form group`..

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" type="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/116928