# Length of input in inline-form screwed up in bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The input length in inline form  isn't modified via `col` syntax after upgrading to boostrap 3.1.1
Before the upgrade (3.0.0) the code from question below was solving the problem.

[Lenght of form-inline's input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044305/lenght-of-form-inlines-input)

Here's working http://www.bootply.com/116928
and here's not http://www.bootply.com/123760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encountering the effects of [this commit (`2979e4bcea`)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/2979e4bcea25c428c801d77153dc0f663618ce20#diff-57a5fbf005ecc202d1e7e08c11f73b93R339):

> - Sets `width: auto;` on all `.form-control`s within inline forms.

```
 .form-inline {

   // Kick in the inline
   @media (min-width: @screen-sm) {
     ...

     // In navbar-form, allow folks to *not* use `.form-group`
     .form-control {
       display: inline-block;
+      width: auto; // Prevent labels from stacking above inputs in `.form-group`
       vertical-align: middle;
     }
```

So, you'll need to manually set `width: 100%` on the `<input>` in question via a bit of custom CSS.